# How to consume soap service in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I am new in react native and wanted to consume soap service but did not get any api to do that. I have used fetch api for Rest service with json parser. Is there any api available to consume soap service and parse xml in react-native. In ios we create soap envelope and send to the server like :

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<GetCitiesByCountry xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">\n"
                         "<CountryName>%@</CountryName>\n"
                         "</GetCitiesByCountry>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n",@"India"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest addValue: @"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry"
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]]
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

NSURLSession *soapSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [soapSession dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest];

[dataTask resume];
```

Same thing I am looking in react-native.

Comment: Sorry for my post, have deleted it, the package seems to have too many compatibility issues and its a node package for server side node, but if you happen to find a solution, please post as answer, in desperate need of one myself.

Comment: Any luck? I've tried the `soap-everywhere` package which seems to work, but there is no associated public git repo, which is a bit worrying.

Comment: any update here..i am also looking for soap api calling in react native